# TypeScript: JSDoc description for generic type parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, jsdoc

In a TypeScript file, how can I write JSDoc documentation for the **generic type parameter** of a function?

In the following dummy example, I tried to use `@param T` to provide documentation on the generic type parameter `T`:

```js
/**
 * A function that processes an array.
 * @param arr The array to be processed.
 * @param T The type of each element in the array.
 */
function processArray<T>(arr: T[]) {
  console.log(arr);
  /* ... */
}
```

([Link to TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgAIUhBSBmBXAdgYwC4EsD2LIYAWAhhpAA4BOOaApgM70OTH7GWXECeAdFDAAFy7YgFsWHSABVCtCZy4EckAEZyqNBkwAmfaJCEjxU6bIJdycnAki1iaQrYA2tUbRRks+InPYK9IMDgyOjYeBTUdIywHNwAPFIAfAAUfgBc0gDaALoAlJAA3lCQaHj0OC48TjgA5qkcuQDcxaCQPO3QQQC+QA))

When I hover over the function parameter `arr`, the documentation tooltip can show the description that I provided via `@param arr`.

[image: documentation for arr]

However, when I hover over the generic type parameter `T`, it does not show the documentation that I provided via `@param T`:

[image: documentation tooltip of generic type parameter]

Which JSDoc tag should I use such that the documentation can show inside the tooltip of the generic type parameter? If that is not supported, is it a good practice to use the `@param` tag (e.g. `@param T`)?

Comment: Found in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65689718/how-to-pass-a-generic-type-argument-with-jsdoc), it suggests to use `@template T`.