How to pass generic type while calling a function?
How to pass generic type while calling a function using JSDoc. This generic type is not part of any actual parameters.
/**
 * @template T
 * @template {string} C
 * @param {string} param1 
 * @param {string} param2
 * @param {C[]} except - Properties in the object to cache.
 * 
 * @returns {Promise<{ data1: Pick<T, C>, data2: string, data3: string }>}
 */
const functionName = async function(param1, param2, except = []) {
  return {
    data1: {},
    data2: '',
    data3: ''
  };
}

const res = await functionName('foo1', 'foo2', ['prop1', 'prop2'])

In this example, while calling functionName I want to pass the parameter T

You mean passing a generic like this functionName<T>()?

Yes. Passing generic type using JSDoc

https://stackoverflow.com/q/65689718/18954618
